# PCRE: (+) and (-) look ahead/behind (Regex)

Tags: html, regex, pcre, lookbehind, regex-lookarounds

I have the following string:

```
<A href="CarPage.asp?parent=CAR123+++&Color=RED">The Car is Red - Its Fast</a>
```

And I want to extract:

- CAR123
- RED
- The Car is Red - Its Fast

What I have so far is:

```
(?<=<A href="CarPage\.asp\?parent=)[A-Za-z0-9]*(\+\+\+&Color=)[A-Za-z0-9]{3}(\">)[A-Za-z0-9\- ]*(?=</a>)
```

But I'm not sure how to set up positive and negative lookahead and lookbehinds when they are not on the string boundaries.

I know, it's HTML...I've heard it before... "Don't parse html with regex..."
I don't need anything more elaborate than this.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use a parser, but if your link is always formatted in the exact same way (no ids, classes, extra params, params in a different order, etc, try:

```
parent=(\w+?)\+*&Color=(\w+?)">(.*?)<
```

The different with Mu's suggestion is the greediness.

Comment: Indeed, the greediness was the kicker. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything that complicated, you can probably get away with this:

```
/parent=(\w+).*Color=(\w+).*>(.*)</
```

And then pull the parts out of `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`. You might have to tighten up the `.*` parts a bit depending on how variable your real input is.

For example, this bit of Perl:

```
my $s = '<A href="CarPage.asp?parent=CAR123+++&Color=RED">The Car is Red - Its Fast</a>';
$s =~ /parent=(\w+).*Color=(\w+).*>(.*)</;
print join("\n", $1, $2, $3), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
CAR123
RED
The Car is Red - Its Fast
```